# does Using clean URL's with query strings change the path/directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

When i use .htaccess and mod_rewrite to redirect my url with query strings,

for example: `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?group=A&id=23`

to a Url like this: `http://www.mysite.com/index/A/23`

Does this change the path on my server, with is used to link to .css and .js files?

So when i have a **main.css** in the same folder as **index.php**, do i have to change the link to this file to like:
`<link href="../../main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Or can i stay with this:
`<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: seems like something you could just test yourself

Answer (score 0):

Yes that changes the path that the browser will send. The browser does not know about your `mod_rewrite` rules at all.